# GitHub's API now rejects HTTP requests without a User-Agent - can anyone tell me why?

Tags: rest, http, security, github, http-headers

According to https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required, and since April 2013 (see https://developer.github.com/changes/2013-04-24-user-agent-required/), all HTTP requests to the GitHub API are required to have a `User-Agent` header.

This is *fine*, since most user agents *do* send that header.

However, what I'm failing to understand completely is *why* was that decision made, or more generally, why would it be a benefit to require `User-Agent`? And is this something I should be doing for my HTTP-based services too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracking and debug purposes, mostly. They say in the documentation: " We request that you use your GitHub username, or the name of your application, for the User-Agent header value. This allows us to contact you if there are problems." This allows them to easily contact you if your application is buggy or misbehaving. They can also track which users/applications are using the API.

(Of course, you can supply any value you want as the user agent, but if you're playing nicely you'll honor their request to use your GitHub username or application name.)